# \footnotetext on different page from \footnotemark

Tags: footnotes, floats, captions

I was forced to use `\footnotetext` and `\footnotemark` on because I needed a footnote in a couple of captions. Of the three times this is done in the article: one works fine, the second appears on the page after the caption and the third appears on the page before the caption.

Is there a way to get this to work properly? I tried using the `footnote` package but then the actual footnote text did not appear.

My preamble and example code (obviously not long enough to show that they appear on two different pages, but hopefully enough to point out if I am doing something incorrectly):

```
\documentclass[reqno]{amsart}
\usepackage{amssymb,latexsym}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{subfig}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{margin=0pt, parskip=0pt, hangindent=0pt, indention=0pt, labelformat=parens, labelfont=rm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\newtheorem{notation}{Notation}
\linespread{1.6}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=.7]{toroids} 
\caption{A sphere, a torus, a 2-torus, a 3-torus, etc.\protect\footnotemark}
\label{fig:toroids} 
\end{figure}
\footnotetext{This figure adapted from p24 of  \cite{topo}. }
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is caused by a similar problem as your last question. The `\footnotetext` is outside the `figure` and thus when the figure is moved to a different page, the footnote is not moved with it. I don't know how to solve this though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is unlikely to be able to be done in a satisfactory way. One could envision moving the `\footnotetext` around based on page references. That would likely work in some cases (but be a hassle to implement) but in some cases, moving the `\footnotetext` would case the `figure` to float to another page and thus the `\footnotetext` would have to move again. It's quite easy to imagine that the iterative process never terminating.

Another problem is that your footnotes will be out of order. This is very easy to demonstrate.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
one\footnote{one}
\begin{figure}[t]
two\footnotemark
\end{figure}
\footnotetext{two}
three\footnote{three}
\end{document}
```

That's almost certainly not what you want.

In most cases, footnotes in figures (or more often in tables) use different markings like an asterisk or a dagger and then the text appears in the figure caption.

Answer (score 6):

A workaround would be to put the content of the `{figure}` inside a `{minipage}`. The footnote will then appear at the bottom of the figure (not at the bottom of the page), and the numbering will be `a,b,c,...` instead of `1,2,3,...` and will be specific to each figure.

Altough it's not exactly what you asked for, the advantage of this method is that you are sure that the footnote text and footnote number are always on the same page and it's certainly simpler than trying to hack through the float mecanism to ensure that footnote text is always on the same page as the figure.

Here's a full code example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-3]

\begin{figure}[t]
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}\centering
\vrule height 10cm width 5cm

text\footnote{foottext}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: the caption command yields strange results though

Comment: @pluton: yes, it is not perfect, but you can have the footnote either before or after the caption depending on whether you put the `\caption` inside the `{minipage}` or not. And if you want more space between the caption and the footnote, you can use an appropriate `\vspace`.

Comment: I tried this quickly (I was facing a deadline for the paper I was working on), but will definitely look into this more when I run into this issue again! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

you can move the `\footnotetext{}` such that it'll be on the correct page (i.e. before the `\footnotemark`). However specify how to label the text like: `\footnotetext[the corresponding number to the mark]{}`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) I am not sure if your answer isn't covered in the accepted answer already ...

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem where the footnote appeared on the previous page (=OP's third case). I.e. figure with footnote marker on page n and footnote text was on page n-1. I found a way to push the footnote to page n as well by using the `\afterpage` command. In my case

```
\begin{figure}[t!]
    \caption{Title title title}
    \captiontext{bla bla bla\footnotemark}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{fig.pdf}
\end{figure}
\afterpage{\footnotetext{text text text}}
```

Comment: (Noting one needs `\usepackage{afterpage}`.) This pushed my waylaid footnote from page n-4 to page n+10, so although it did something, it didn't work for me.