# biblatex: Remove parentheses around year for articles

Tags: biblatex

Two questions remain while I try to finish my dissertation. I hope all you experts can help me quickly:

- I use the following setup for `biblatex`:

  ```
  \usepackage[backend=bibtex,bibstyle=authortitle,firstinits,terseinits,citestyle=authoryear]{biblatex} %
  ```

  and have noticed that when I have a year entry for an article, it appears in the bibliography in parentheses, whereas when I have a book, or misc, or patent entry, it does not. How can I get rid of the parentheses in the article references?
- How do I properly add a footcite to the caption of an image? I tried the following:

  ```
  \begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \includegraphics{images/img.JPG}
   \caption{Caption goes here \protect\footnotemark }
   \label{fig:img1}
  \end{figure}
  \footcitetext{source1}
  ```

When a floating image is moved to a new page, the footnote remains on the old page however. Have any of you an idea on how to footcite properly inside a caption?

Thanks for all your help, you guys rock!

Comment: You shouldn't ask more than one question at a time. For issues 1 and 3 have a look at the `biblatex` manual (hint for 1: options `citestyle` and `bibstyle`). For issue 2 see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19105/how-can-i-put-more-space-between-bibliography-entries-biblatex. Issue 5 is not about `biblatex`. Consider to edit your question so that only issue 4 remains (and perhaps add an example).

Comment: hi, thanks for the infos, that already helped a lot!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm not sure if this has come up before -- you need to redefine the `issue+date` bibmacro (which is used by the `@article` driver).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authortitle]{biblatex}

\renewbibmacro*{issue+date}{%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}% NEW
%  \printtext[parens]{% DELETED
    \iffieldundef{issue}
      {\usebibmacro{date}}
      {\printfield{issue}%
       \setunit*{\addspace}%
%       \usebibmacro{date}}}% DELETED
       \usebibmacro{date}}% NEW
  \newunit}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Bli74,
  hyphenation = {english},
  author = {Blinder, Alan S.},
  year = {1974},
  title = {The economics of brushing teeth},
  journaltitle = {Journal of Political Economy},
  volume = {82},
  number = {4},
  pages = {887--891},
}
@book{Kop04,
  hyphenation = {ngerman},
  author = {Kopka, Helmut and Daly, Patrick W.},
  year = {2004},
  title = {Guide to \LaTeX},
  edition = {4},
  location = {Boston},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

The positioning of footnotes related to floats is a tricky issue; have, e.g., a look at [\footnotetext on different page from \footnotemark](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7078/footnotetext-on-different-page-from-footnotemark).