# biblatex verbose style @article bib-- remove parenthesis around year and month

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, formatting, citing

I'm using biblatex with `verbose-ibid` style. For one of the `@article` entries, I have the following:

```
@article{ref_133,
  title = {IBM wants Minneapolis to become a 'smarter city'},
  author = {Alexander, Steve},
  journal = {Minneapolis Star Tribune},
  url = {http://www.startribune.com/business/123289493.html},
  year = "2011",
  month = "6"
}
```

which renders as:
[image]

How can I customize `year` (and `month` and `day`) so that it's not enclosed by parentheses?

```
  Alexander, Steve, "IBM wants Minneapolis to become a 'smarter city.'"
  Minneapolis Star Tribune. June 2011. URL: http://www.startribune.com/business/123289493.html.
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66161/biblatex-remove-parentheses-around-year-for-articles) fixed it:

```
\renewbibmacro*{issue+date}{%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}% NEW
%  \printtext[parens]{% DELETED
    \iffieldundef{issue}
      {\usebibmacro{date}}
      {\printfield{issue}%
       \setunit*{\addspace}%
%       \usebibmacro{date}}}% DELETED
       \usebibmacro{date}}% NEW
  \newunit}
```