# Removing the parentheses around year does not work

Tags: biblatex

I have to comply to the style guidelines of some freaking academic journal. As usual, they always let the author do the work, but this one is pretty tedious even from the initial submission. What's left for me is to get rid of the brackets around the year. What I need in particular is this:
[image]

As this question has been [asked and answered before](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66161/biblatex-remove-parentheses-around-year-for-articles?rq=1), I tried to adapt that solution, but it does not work out for me. I include biblatex with my preferred settings in the MWE, but reducing it to 'style=authoryear' as the only option does not help either. Other than the biblatex call, I did exactly as in the linked question. Did biblatex change in the meantime to let this crash?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,sorting=nyt,isbn=false,doi=false,clearlang=false,
backend=biber,natbib=true,hyperref=true,giveninits=false,useprefix=true,
backref=false,maxcitenames=2,uniquelist=false,uniquename=init,
maxbibnames=10]{biblatex}
\renewbibmacro*{issue+date}{%
\setunit{\addcomma\space}% NEW
%  \printtext[parens]{% DELETED
\iffieldundef{issue}
{\usebibmacro{date}}
{\printfield{issue}%
    \setunit*{\addspace}%
    %       \usebibmacro{date}}}% DELETED
    \usebibmacro{date}}% NEW
\newunit}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Bli74,
    hyphenation = {english},
    author = {Blinder, Alan S.},
    year = {1974},
    title = {The economics of brushing teeth},
    journaltitle = {Journal of Political Economy},
    volume = {82},
    number = {4},
    pages = {887--891},
}
@book{Kop04,
    hyphenation = {ngerman},
    author = {Kopka, Helmut and Daly, Patrick W.},
    year = {2004},
    title = {Guide to \LaTeX},
    edition = {4},
    location = {Boston},
    publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: This is the working MWE, tnanks to Moewe's link in the comments.

```
\documentclass{article}
 \usepackage[style=authoryear,sorting=nyt,isbn=false,doi=false,clearlang=false,backend=biber,natbib=true,hyperref=true,giveninits=false,useprefix=true,backref=false,maxcitenames=2,uniquelist=false,uniquename=init,maxbibnames=10]{biblatex}

\usepackage{xpatch,filecontents}
\xpatchbibmacro{date+extradate}{%
\printtext[parens]%
}{%
\setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
\printtext%
}{}{} 


\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Bli74,
    hyphenation = {english},
    author = {Blinder, Alan S.},
    year = {1974},
    title = {The economics of brushing teeth},
    journaltitle = {Journal of Political Economy},
    volume = {82},
    number = {4},
    pages = {887--891},
}
@book{Kop04,
    hyphenation = {ngerman},
    author = {Kopka, Helmut and Daly, Patrick W.},
    year = {2004},
    title = {Guide to \LaTeX},
    edition = {4},
    location = {Boston},
    publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\nocite{*}
\begin{document}    
\printbibliography  
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide a bit more information about your formatting needs. In particular, what kind of separator should there be between the author block and year: a period (aka "full stop"), a comma, nothing at all, or something else? And is having a period between the year and title blocks correct? Please advise.

Comment: thanks, I added the required format above. And I realize the MWE does not fulfil the example, but I did not insert the other adaptions.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/428190/35864. But please note that very few journals (if any at all) can accept `biblatex` submissions: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12175/35864. Double check with the submission guidelines or the editor if they can accept `biblatex`. Many journals have LaTeX templates that include directions to produce a bibliography, some journals have pre-built `.bst` styles. I have yet to come across one that encourages `biblatex`.

Comment: Note that https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/66161/35864 is actually only about removing the parentheses around the year for `@article`s in `authortitle` and similar bibliography styles. But you want to get rid of the parentheses around the year for all entry types in an `authoryear` style, where different modifications are needed. So https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/428190/35864 is what you are looking for. As you can see from the fact that this is v3 of the question, some things have indeed changed, but those things did not have an influence on your code not doing the right thing.

Comment: thanks moewe, the second answer in the last link did the trick. Actually, I submit a PDF, the source file is only for backup. The journal actually provides a template, but in this template all bibitems are inserted 'by hand'.

Comment: So can we close this as a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/428190/35864