# Remove brackets around year in biblatex authoryear

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, authoryear

I would like to remove the brackets around the year in `authoryear` style in `biblatex`. I have seen a solution for `authortitle` [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66161/biblatex-remove-parentheses-around-year-for-articles), which does not work for me.

I have tried redefining the `issue+date` bibmacro as specified in the previous answer. (By copy+pasting the code into my document, I have not tried to adjust it in any way). Also, I have tried specifying `\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{year}{#1}`. Both attempts have no effect on how my bibliography looks.
Let's say I have a `.bib` file `my_ref.bib` containing one reference:

```
@Article{Danecek2011,
  author   = {Danecek, Petr and Auton, Adam and Abecasis, Goncalo and Albers, Cornelis A. and Banks, Eric and DePristo, Mark A. and Handsaker, Robert E. and Lunter, Gerton and Marth, Gabor T. and Sherry, Stephen T. and McVean, Gilean and Durbin, Richard and 1000 Genomes Project Analysis Group},
  title    = {{The variant call format and VCFtools}},
  journal  = {Bioinformatics},
  year     = {2011},
  volume   = {27},
  number   = {15},
  pages    = {2156-2158},
  doi      = {10.1093/bioinformatics/btr330},
}
```

I call `biblatex` via:

```
% !BIB TS-program = biber
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=2.6cm, right=2.9cm, top=3.5cm, bottom=3.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[sorting=nyt, citestyle = authoryear,  bibstyle = authoryear, giveninits=true, isbn = false, url = false, eprint = false, doi = false, dashed = false, uniquelist = minyear, maxcitenames = 2, maxbibnames = 7, backend = biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{my_ref.bib}
\begin{document}
\cite{Danecek2011}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The output is:

> Danecek, P. et al. (2011): "The variant call format and VCFtools". In: Bioinformatics 27.15, pp. 2156-2158.

I would like to receive:

> Danecek, P. et al. 2011: "The variant call format and VCFtools". In: Bioinformatics 27.15, pp. 2156-2158.

Comment: Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/428190/35864.

Comment: Not relevant to the question, but `citestyle = authoryear,  bibstyle = authoryear` is completely equivalent to the shorter `style = authoryear`. With those style settings `sorting=nyt,` is already preset, so need not be given explicitly.

Comment: Since your self-answer just reiterates that you took one of the answers to https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/428190/35864 I decided to close the question as a duplicate. That way all relevant information is concentrated on one question and not spread around in many threads. Your Q&A should remain searchable and may help future visitors find the other thread.

Answer (score 0):

The post [How to (properly) remove the parentheses around the year in authoryear style? (v3)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/428190/how-to-properly-remove-the-parentheses-around-the-year-in-authoryear-style-v) contains the answer:
defining `style=ext-authoryear` and `\DeclareFieldFormat{biblabeldate}{#1}` has the desired effect.