# Footnote in tabular environment

Tags: tables, environments, footnotes

I thought that footnotes would have only a problem with the `table` environment, but none of the answers in

- [Footnotes in Tabulars?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35200/footnotes-in-tabulars)
- [Footnote in table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35615/footnote-in-table)

seem to work for the `tabular` environment.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l}
Content\footnote{Footnote}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: what about the classic `\footnotemark`/`\footnotetext` approach?

Comment: Another simple way to use `\footnote` is to wrap \begin{tabular} in a minipage. Just surround it with `\begin{minipage}{\linewidth} ... \end{minipage}`. The footnote numbers will be the letters `a, b, ...`

Answer (score 87, accepted):

another possibility is with the `footnote` package and `\makesavenoteenv{tabular}`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{footnote}
\makesavenoteenv{tabular}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l}
Content\footnote{footnote text}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

If 
 one has both tabular-only environment and tabular inside table, it is possibile to load both `\makesavenoteenv{tabular}` and `\makesavenoteenv{table}` in the preamble, like this:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{footnote}
\makesavenoteenv{tabular}
\makesavenoteenv{table}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{l}
Content\footnote{footnote text}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{tabular}{l}
Content\footnote{footnote text}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

So to have a more general solution.

Also, a fairly comprehensive list of solutions can be found inside the [documentation](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/tablefootnote/tablefootnote.pdf) for the `tablefootnote`package, starting from page 3, section "Alternatives".

Comment: But this unfortunately works only if one has no table environment around it.

Comment: ah! I thought the question was exactly to provide a solution for the case when there is only a `tabular` environment, not inside a `table`, as per your MWE. If your tabular is inside a table you can use the `tablefootnote` package, as per your first link

Comment: Your first answer is completely right, but I am always interested in answers that can be generalized.

Comment: I see it now... if you want a unified approach with the `footnote` package, just load both `\makesavenoteenv{tabular}` and `\makesavenoteenv{table}` and you're all set :)

Comment: This would be perfect with some little explanation of what's going on under the hood, I mean, what those commands are doing.

Comment: @jasikevicius23, I'd leave that to the `footnote` package documentation. However please feel free to edit the answer if you think it can be improved in any way.

Comment: Note that (as mentioned in the linked documentation) hyperlinks from the footnote mark to the text do not work properly for this solution.

Comment: @Marijn The `footnotehyper` package has superseded the original `footnote`, fixing the hyperlinks problem.

Answer (score 98):

For some reason (my preferred choice) the [`tablefootnote` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tablefootnote) only works if you wrap the `tabular` in a `table` float. A way around is to use `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\begin{document}    
before

\begin{tabular}{l}
Content\footnotemark\\
Content continued\footnotemark\\
Content continued further\footnotemark
\end{tabular}
\footnotetext[1]{Footnote}
\footnotetext[2]{Second footnote}
\footnotetext{Third footnote}

after
\end{document}
```

Note how manual numbering of all but the first footnotetext is necessary. In a longer document, an approach with manually decrementing and incrementing the footnote number might be more viable; that way, the only way you have to watch out for is decrementing by the correct number:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\begin{document}    
before

\begin{tabular}{l}
Content\footnotemark\\
Content continued\footnotemark\\
Content continued further\footnotemark
\end{tabular}
\addtocounter{footnote}{-2}
\footnotetext{Footnote}
\addtocounter{footnote}{1}
\footnotetext{Second footnote}
\addtocounter{footnote}{1}
\footnotetext{Third footnote}

after
\end{document}
```

[image: sample output]

Comment: I need to upvote this! Exactly [what I commented](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109467/footnote-in-tabular-environment#comment240016_109467), too ;)

Comment: @cgnieder: Thanks for appreciating my originality. `:D` I was typing up the answer when you posted your comment.

Comment: @CountZero: This works great even with surrounding table environment! Thanks. But I understand that most people do not prefer it this way around.

Comment: Didn't work for me, \footnotetext content was not rendered at all

Comment: FYI separating `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext` risks placing of the footnote content on a different page [in some cases](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7078/footnotetext-on-different-page-from-footnotemark).

Comment: Placing multiple `\footnotemark` in the same table required manual numbering in the `\footnotetext[number]{text}` command in my case.

Comment: @HennadiiMadan: One has to put the `\footnotetext` outside the table environment.

Comment: @HodossySzabolcs I wonder if there is a way around the manual numbering. Manual numbering goes against one of the strong points of using LaTeX

Comment: @HackerBoss See the edited answer. You still have to adjust the first `\addtocount{footnote}{-X}` so that `X=number of footnotes in the table - 1` whenever you change the number of footnotes inside the table; in case of extra large tables with dozens of footnotes, you could store the current value of the `footnote` counter before the table and then reset it to that value before the first `footnotetext` command.

Answer (score 24):

You can also use [`threeparttable`](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/threeparttable) package to insert footnotes in the tables.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\caption{Example of test session results}
\label{tab:test_results}
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
  \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
    \hline
    Mutants & CPU\tnote{1}     & Memory\tnote{2}    \\ \hline
    Mutant-1   & 23 & 15 \\ \hline
    Mutant-2   & 32 & 11 \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \begin{tablenotes}
    \item[1] Measured in percentages.
    \item[2] Measured in kilobytes (KB).
  \end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

**Output:**

[image: Table]

Comment: Do I understand correctly that this will change the layout of the rest of the table?

Comment: I don't think so. I have updated the answer to show how the table would look like.

Comment: This was a lifesaver.  The other answers did not work for me, and threeparttable looks fantastic.  It's simple to write and keeps the notes with the table.

Answer (score 7):

I insert footnotes manually at the bottom of the table, which is pretty simple and requires no additional package:

```
\begin{table}
\caption{The Table.}
\centering
  \begin{tabular}{lrr}
   \hline
          & Variable A & Variable B \\
   \hline
      Item 1        & 234.5 & 678.9 \\
      Item 2~$^{1}$ & 432.1 & 876.5 \\
   \hline
   \multicolumn{3}{l}{$^{1}$\footnotesize{Here is a footnote.}} \\
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Note that `\footnotesize` takes no argument, and **changes the size of all the text following it** (until the end of the group). So the `{...}` after `\footnotesize` is **misleading**.

Answer (score 3):

If you use `bidiftnxtra` (a part of `bidi` package), all combinations of `table` and `tabular` will work. Ofcourse, this only work if you are using xelatex but the approach can be ported to other packages too:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{bidi}
\usepackage{bidiftnxtra}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l}
Content\footnote{Footnote}
\end{tabular}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l}
Content\footnote{Footnote}
\end{tabular}
\caption{This is a caption\footnote{Another footnote.}}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This no longer works.

Answer (score 2):

I particularly like @CountZero's answer, yet it may happen that your footnote mark is on a different page than your footnote text. In that case, you can move around the `\footnotetext` to solve that, but how do you become aware of it in the first place?

This code will issue a warning when that happens:

```
\documentclass{article}

% works with hyperref, too:
% \usepackage{hyperref}

% Footnotes in table with page-number check
\usepackage{refcount}
\newcommand{\myfootnotemark}{\footnotemark\label{fn:mark}}
\newcommand{\myfootnotetext}[1]{\footnotetext{#1\label{fn:text}%
        \edef\fnmark{\getpagerefnumber{fn:mark}}%
        \edef\fntext{\getpagerefnumber{fn:text}}%
        \ifx\fnmark\fntext\else\ClassWarning{}{footnote mark and text on different pages!}\fi}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{l}
%       Table stuff \footnote{This does not work: the footnote is missing.}
        Table stuff \myfootnotemark
    \end{tabular}

% uncomment to see the warning:
% \pagebreak

\myfootnotetext{So we do this instead!}

\end{document}
```

It works only for a single `\footnotemark`/`\footnotetext` pair so far, but extension should not be too difficult and those who use this weird hack more than once in a document are hopefully apt enough to adapt my code accordingly :)

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution with `talltblr` environment of [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htbp]
\centering
\begin{talltblr}[
  caption = {Long Long Long Long Tabular},
  note{a} = {It is the first footnote.},
  note{b} = {It is the second long long long long long long footnote.},
]{
  colspec = {XXX}, width = 0.8\linewidth, hlines,
}
 Alpha   & Beta & Gamma\TblrNote{a} \\
 Epsilon & Zeta & Eta   \\
 Iota    & Kapp & Lambdaa\TblrNote{b} \\
\end{talltblr}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The package `nicematrix` provides an environment `{NiceTabular}` which is similar to the classical `{tabular}` (of `array`) but this extra features.

- When the package is loaded with the key `footnote` or the key `footnotehyper`, the commands `\footnote` are extracted from the tabular (by using the corresponding package: `footnote` or `footnotehyper`).
- There is a command `\tabularnote` from notes which are composed under the tabular.

Demonstrating example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{height=10cm} % in order to have a smaller output (for this post)

\usepackage{booktabs,enumitem}
\usepackage[footnotehyper]{nicematrix}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{l}
\toprule
Content in the first row\tabularnote{A tabular note} \\
Some content in the second row\footnote{A footnote} \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 1):

Use the `footnotehyper` package.

#### Usage

Just insert

```
\usepackage{footnotehyper}
\makesavenoteenv{table}
\makesavenoteenv{tabular}
```

in the preamble.

#### Example

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{footnotehyper}
\makesavenoteenv{table}
\makesavenoteenv{tabular}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[p]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
    \hline
    Item 1 & Item 2\footnote{Footnote of the floating table on the other page.} \\
    \hline
    Item 3\footnote{Another footnote of the floating table on the other page.} & Item 4 \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Table with Hyperref Support and Multiple Footnotes}
\end{table}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
  \hline
  Item 5\footnote{Footnote in tabular environment.} & Item 6\footnote{Footnote in tabular environment.} \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

#### Limitation

As mentioned in the package documentation, even though the footnotes will show up for floating environments, they may be not on the correct page. For `tabular` environment, it works fine.

[image: documentation]

#### Comparison

This is an extensive comparison of all the solutions listed.

Features to be tested:

1. hyperref support
2. footnotetext are placed on the correct page where the footnotemark appear for floating table
3. automatic numbering when there are multiple footnotes
4. footnotes are placed below the table/at the bottom of the page
5. support for `tabular` environment itself without `table` environment around it
6. support for floating environment, `tabular` inside `table`

| Package | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| footnotehyper | yes | no | yes | bottom of the page | yes | yes |
| footnote | one link per table | no | yes | bottom of the page | yes | yes |
| tablefootnote | yes | no | yes | bottom of the page | no | yes |
| longtable | only go to last page | no | yes | bottom of the page | yes | yes |
| ftnxtra | no | no | yes | bottom of the page | yes | no |
| threeparttable | no | yes | yes | below the table | yes | yes |
| tabularx | no | no | yes | bottom of the page | yes | no |
| bidiftnxtra | no | no | yes | bottom of the page | yes | no |
| nicematrix | yes | no | yes | both supported | yes | no |
| tabularray | yes | yes | no | below the table | yes | yes |
| raw footnotemark/footnotetext | one link per table | no | yes | bottom of the page | yes | no |

The source code for the comparison, as well as links to original answer suggesting the package, can be found at https://gist.github.com/user202729/09825890622de02512e750e04eee41d4 .

#### Things missing here

Things that could be tested, but isn't:

- Ulrike Fischer's answer at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/314374/250119
- Joseph Wright's answer at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35275/250119

Features that could be tested, but isn't:

7. support for `align` environment from `amsmath`

Answer (score 0):

As also posted [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/695113/137109), you can also use define a footnote *outside* the table/tabular by using a custom command `marklessfootnote`, and *then refer* to it within the table instead.

```
\newcommand\marklessfootnote[1]{
    \addtocounter{footnote}{1}
    \footnotetext{#1}
}
```

The `marklessfootnote` can then be referred to within a table using a regular `\ref` command, or the `cleveref` package command `\cref` with ease, also compatible with `hyperref` package.

**Ref:**

```
%... inside my doc
\marklessfootnote{My footnote \label{ftn:01}}
%... inside my tabular...
\textsuperscript{\tiny\ref{ftn:01}} % With commands to superscript the mark.
```

**Cleveref:**

Note to make Cref link the same style as the regular footnote, you can redefine the format as follows.

```
\crefformat{footnote}{#2\textsuperscript{\footnotemark[#1]}#3} %option to superscript mark.
%... %inside my doc
\marklessfootnote{My footnote \label{ftn:01}}
%... %inside my tabular...
\cref{ftn:01}
```

Comment: Need to fix hyperref link to markless footnote, as commented on [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/695113/137109) post.