# How to insert footnote with latex \input?

Tags: footnotes, input, external-files

I have two tex files and use the command `\input` to include the table on my main file as follows:

**Main.tex**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{inconsolata}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}

\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{listings}


\begin{document}

Eos ea harum labores scaevola, mea autem vivendo interesset ne, vis verterem patrioque at. Et adhuc malis perpetua quo. Aperiri deseruisse qui in, sea nihil aperiri et. Per tale dolore apeirian at, nam reque liber meliore id.

\input{table}

Euismod meliore duo te, at vivendo officiis per. Ea verterem lucilius urbanitas duo, nibh autem tamquam eu sea. Feugait mediocrem vel an, eu graecis tibique vulputate pro. Ne aperiri facilis scriptorem vix. Ad sed causae virtute antiopam, te usu suas sale neglegentur, tation quidam delenit has ne.

\end{document}
```

**Table.tex**

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{center}
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabular}{|l|}
\hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0} 
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}\textbf{Saucelabs\footnote{\textit{Saucelabs}: \url{https://wiki.saucelabs.com/display/DOCS/Test+Configuration+Options/}}}} \\ \hline
Browser Name                                                        \\ \hline
Browser Version                                                     \\ \hline
Platform Name                                                       \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

**Result**

[image]

How do I that the footnote in the table header to appear on the main page?

Comment: Have you compiled your document twice?

Comment: This would help: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109467/footnote-in-tabular-environment

Comment: Hello  Romain Picot, I'm using sharelatex. I compile twice, but still not displaying the footnote.

Comment: `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext` solves this (http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/177030/46716)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your MWE did not work for me, so I commented out `\usepackage{minted}`.
The easiest way for me to solve your problem was to split the footnote-order in two orders: `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext{Some text to indicate a reference.}`

```
%In main.tex add:
\input{table}\footnotetext{{\textit{Saucelabs}: \url{https://wiki.saucelabs.com/display/DOCS/Test+Configuration+Options/}}}

%In table.tex change to:
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}\textbf{Saucelabs\footnotemark}} \\ \hline
```

Perhaps there is a nicer way in achieving this. But for a quick solution it might work.
If your are using several different footnotes, you can call an argument for `\footnotemark[17]` and `\footnotetext[17]{Some Text that will be footnote with the number 17.}`

Best

Comment: Thank​ you so much for your help @HATEthePLOT, now it's all working!

Comment: Hello @HATEthePLOT,I ended up using the `\tablefootnote` with the package `\usepackage{tablefootnote}` for the correct numbering of the footnote was not working. But either way you surely helped me a lot. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 5):

Is the following what you intended (please note that the question is unrelated to `\input` command, see below):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\begin{document}

Eos ea harum labores scaevola, mea autem vivendo interesset ne, vis.

\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{center}
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabular}{|l|}
\hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}\textbf{Saucelabs}\footnotemark}      \\ \hline
Browser Name                                                                       \\ \hline
Browser Version                                                                    \\ \hline
Platform Name                                                                      \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}

Euismod meliore duo te, at vivendo officiis per. Ea verterem lucilius. 

\footnotetext{\url{https://wiki.saucelabs.com/display/DOCS/Test+Configuration+Options/}}
\end{document}
```

Same example with an `\input` command

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{url,filecontents}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\begin{filecontents}{ifil}
\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{center}
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabular}{|l|}
\hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}\textbf{Saucelabs}\footnotemark}      \\ \hline
Browser Name                                                                       \\ \hline
Browser Version                                                                    \\ \hline
Platform Name                                                                      \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}

Eos ea harum labores scaevola, mea autem vivendo interesset.

\input{ifil}

Euismod meliore duo te, at vivendo officiis per. 

\footnotetext{\url{https://wiki.saucelabs.com/display/DOCS/Test+Configuration+Options/}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello @Denis, thank you so much for your help!