# foot note the table element

Tags: tables, footnotes

I have a table in latex like:

```
\begin{table}[h]

  \centering
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{.5\tabcolsep}%
  \begin{tabular}{ l @{\qquad} ccc }
   \toprule
   & \makecell[b]{\textbf{A}} & \textbf{B}   
   \\
   \midrule
  p1 & False &  True\\
    \bottomrule
 \end{tabular}
\caption{test}
\label{table_example}
\end{table}
```

I want to add a foot note for False. Something like False* and in the footnote of the (bottom of the) page a small description

Thank you

Comment: I suggest you look into the LaTeX package called [threeparttable](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/threeparttable), the package's eponymous LaTeX environment, the package's `\tnote` macro (short for 'table footnote', I suppose), and the package's `tablenotes` environment.

Comment: See this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/327385/101651