# two or more footnotes in a table

Tags: tables, footnotes

*My question is different form the question [Footnote in tabular environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109467/footnote-in-tabular-environment) because I already know how to set footnotes in tabular environments. But I don't know how to correctly use two ore more footnotes that appear together in one table. The other question is not dealing with this special issue.*

---

I have this latex document:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\begin{document}
Text before the table\footnote{This is the 1st footnote}

\begin{tabular}{cl}
$k_B$ & Boltzmann constant\footnotemark $k_B = 1,380649 \cdot 10^{23} J/K$\\ 
$f$ & degrees of freedom\footnotemark \\ 
\end{tabular}
\footnotetext{named after Boltzmann}
\footnotetext{Another word for possibilities}

Text after the table\footnote{This is the last footnote}
\end{document}
```

I get this body, which is ok:

[image: Body with correct numbers for footnotes]

There are four points with footnotes, each of them has its own distinct number, as it should be. Everything is fine here.

But I get these footnotes:

[image: Footnotes with one number wrong]

As you can see, the second footnote (which is the first of two inside the table) has a wrong number. The numbers should be 1-***2***-3-4, but they are 1-***3***-3-4.

How can I get the correct numbers?

---

### === Reaction to an answer ===

Fran posted [an answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/478997/182670) but his solution is just a weak workaround that doesn't work properly in bigger documents with dozens of footnotes.

Suppose you are writing a book, and the table with the two footnotes is on page 580. You create the footnotes like in Fran's workaround, and 3 month later you add another text with another footnote on page 215. I want that all footnotes are correct even after adding or removing preceding footnotes.

An Example:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\chapter*{Issue with footnotes in tables}
\lipsum[1]

% ===========================================================
% Toggle the next line
% Subsequently added text with a new footnote \footnote{additional footnote}
% ===========================================================

\lipsum[66]

Old text with a footnote\footnote{an old footnote} before the table.

\section*{Table}

\begin{tabular}{cl}
$k_B$ & Boltzmann constant\footnotemark[2]\  $k_B = 1,380649 \cdot 10^{23} J/K$\\ 
$f$ & degrees of freedom\footnotemark[3] \\ 
\end{tabular}

\addtocounter{footnote}{2}
\footnotetext[2]{named after Boltzmann}
\footnotetext[3]{Another word for possibilities}

Text immediately after the table\footnote{immediately after the table}

\lipsum[75]

Text with a footnote\footnote{This is the last footnote}
\end{document}
```

This code produces this output:

[image: correct output]

But then I add some Text with another footnote before the table:

```
% ===========================================================
% Toggle the next line
Subsequently added text with a new footnote \footnote{additional footnote}
% ===========================================================
```

and I get this:

[image: output with errors]

Now not only the numbers in the footnotes at the bottom of the page are wrong, but also the numbers in the table itself.

Comment: [Footnote in tabular environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/109467/134144)  might also be interesting.

Comment: Why did you mark this question as a duplicate? I clearly explained why it is different. Didn't you read the first paragraph of my question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\begin{document}
Text before the table\footnote{This is the 1st footnote}

\begin{tabular}{cl}
$k_B$ & Boltzmann constant\footnotemark[2]\  $k_B = 1,380649 \cdot 10^{23} J/K$\\ 
$f$ & degrees of freedom\footnotemark[3] \\ 
\end{tabular}

\addtocounter{footnote}{2}
\footnotetext[2]{named after Boltzmann}
\footnotetext[3]{Another word for possibilities}

Text after the table\footnote{This is the last footnote}

\end{document}
```

**Edit**

Some type of automatic adjust as requested is possible making a new environment for the table notes when  (1) you do not use this in floats, and (2) of course, the number of `\tablefootnotemark`s is the same of  `\tablefootnotext`s for each table:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass[a6paper,twocolumn]{scrbook}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{lipsum,calc,booktabs,parskip}
\newcounter{tablefootnote}
\newcommand\tablefootnotemark{\footnotemark\addtocounter{tablefootnote}{1}} %
\newenvironment{foo}%
{\edef\ntnotes{\thetablefootnote}\setcounter{footnote}%
{\value{footnote}-\value{tablefootnote}}}%
{\edef\ntnotes{\thefootnote}\setcounter{tablefootnote}{0}}
\newcommand\tablefootnotext[1]{\addtocounter{footnote}{1}   \footnotetext{\texttt{[table]} #1}}

\begin{document}
\raggedright
Bla \footnote{footnote 1} bla \footnote{footnote 2} Bla, \footnote{footnote 3} before the table.

\begin{tabular}{cl}\toprule
$foo$ & bah\tablefootnotemark \\ 
$foo$ & bah\tablefootnotemark \\ 
$foo$ & bah\tablefootnotemark \\ 
$foo$ & bah\tablefootnotemark \\\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\begin{foo}
\tablefootnotext{footnote 4}
\tablefootnotext{footnote 5}
\tablefootnotext{footnote 6}
\tablefootnotext{footnote 7}
\end{foo}

Bla \footnote{footnote 8} bla \footnote{footnote 9} Bla, \footnote{footnote 10} after the table.

\begin{tabular}{cl}\toprule
$foo$ & bah\tablefootnotemark \\ 
$foo$ & bah\tablefootnotemark \\ 
$foo$ & bah\tablefootnotemark \\\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\begin{foo}
\tablefootnotext{footnote 11}
\tablefootnotext{footnote 12}
\tablefootnotext{footnote 13}
\end{foo}

Bla \footnote{footnote 14} bla \footnote{footnote 15} Bla, \footnote{footnote 16} after the second table.

\begin{tabular}{cl}\toprule
$foo$ & bah\tablefootnotemark \\ 
$foo$ & bah\tablefootnotemark \\\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\begin{foo}
\tablefootnotext{footnote 17}
\tablefootnotext{footnote 18}
\end{foo}

Bla \footnote{footnote 19} bla \footnote{footnote 20} Bla, \footnote{footnote 21} after the third table.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Footnotes work normally with `longtable`. See [Footnotes in tables](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-footintab):

```latex
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}
Text before the table\footnote{This is the 1st footnote}

\begin{longtable}{cl}
$k_B$ & Boltzmann constant\footnote{named after Boltzmann} $k_B = 1,380649 \cdot 10^{23} J/K$\\ 
$f$ & degrees of freedom\footnote{Another word for possibilities} \\ 
\end{longtable}

Text after the table\footnote{This is the last footnote}
\end{document}
```

Alternatively, if you want to stick with the `tabular` environment, add the `footnotehyper` package:

```latex
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{footnotehyper}
\begin{document}
Text before the table\footnote{This is the 1st footnote}

\begin{tabular}{cl}
$k_B$ & Boltzmann constant\footnote{named after Boltzmann} $k_B = 1,380649 \cdot 10^{23} J/K$\\ 
$f$ & degrees of freedom\footnote{Another word for possibilities} \\ 
\end{tabular}

Text after the table\footnote{This is the last footnote}
\end{document}
```