# Show table footnotes at the end of the page

Tags: tables, footnotes

I have a table which contains footnotes. I want these footnotes to appear at the end of the page, but nothing is displaying. However footnote numbers are there in the table. I have tried doing [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109467/footnote-in-tabular-environment) but it didn't work for me.

This is my table code:

```
\documentclass{book}                                                                                                 

\usepackage{booktabs}                                                                                                

\usepackage{url}                                                                                                     
\usepackage{tabularx}                                                                                                
\usepackage{ragged2e}                                                                                                
\usepackage{makecell}                                                                                                

\begin{document}                                                                                                     

\begin{table}[hbtp]                                                                                                  
    \centering                                                                                                       
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ c >{\RaggedRight}X }                                                               
        \toprule                                                                                                     
        \textbf{$e_\#$} & \makecell[cc]{\textbf{Description}} \\                                                     
        \midrule                                                                                                     
        1 & Cathedral of Notre Dame fire during restorations work\footnote{https://www.nytimes.com/es/2019/04/15/not\
re-dame-incendio/}.  \\ \addlinespace                                                                                
        2 & Beginning of `Semana Santa' vacances in Madrid\footnote{https://www.abc.es/espana/madrid/abci-semana-san\
ta-2019-procesiones-madrid-recorrido-horario-y-programa-201904110105\_noticia.html}. \\ \addlinespace                
        3 & World Art Day\footnote{http://www.aimdigital.com.ar/15-de-abril-dia-mundial-del-arte/}. \\ \addlinespace 
        4 & Max Pradera, an Spanish journalist, posted an unfortunate comment about Almudena Cathedral and Notre Dam\
e\footnote{https://www.abc.es/internacional/abci-pradera-pudiendose-haber-quemado-almudena-y-quema-notre-dame-201904\
160310\_noticia.html}. \\ \addlinespace                                                                              
        5 & Premiere of the last season of Game of Thrones\footnote{https://www.elmundo.es/television/2019/04/09/5ca\
c665ffc6c8393168b46eb.html}. \\                                                                                      
        \bottomrule                                                                                                  
    \end{tabularx}                                                                                                   
   \caption{April 15th 2019 most important events}                                                                   
    \label{tab:april-events}                                                                                         
\end{table}                                                                                                          

\end{document}
```

Comment: What packages and `documentclass` do you use? Just including `tabularx` does not let me compile your table. Could you include a minimal working example (MWE)?

Comment: @Taunch Sorry, I didn't know what to post so I updated my question with my whole `main.tex`

Comment: OK, that was a bit too much ;) I've edited your question so that the example remains "minimal", meaning that only things related to your question (= the table) remain. (The code would have also not compiled, since you seem to use a custom ´thesis.sty´)

Comment: @Taunch Right, I also added it to the question (I may have provided again too much)

Comment: Ah, you really don't need that now, the new MWE does not rely on it anymore and compiles just fine on its own.

Comment: Did you try with \footnote mark and \footnotetext?

Comment: @leandriis I have searched on Internet about that approach and worked perfectly for me. Thanks a lot for the advise

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `footnote` package and exploit its `\makesavenoteenv`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\usepackage{footnote}
\makesavenoteenv{table}
\newcounter{step}
\newcommand\step{\stepcounter{step}\thestep}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering  
  \caption{April 15th 2019 most important events}
  \label{tab:april-events}
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ c >{\RaggedRight}X }
    \toprule
      \textbf{$e_\#$} & \centering\textbf{Description} \tabularnewline
    \midrule
      \step & Cathedral of Notre Dame fire during restorations
      work\footnote{\url{https://www.nytimes.com/es/2019/04/15/notre-dame-incendio/}}. \\
    \addlinespace
      \step & Beginning of `Semana Santa' vacances in
      Madrid\footnote{\url{https://www.abc.es/espana/madrid/abci-semana-santa-2019-procesiones-madrid-recorrido-horario-y-programa-201904110105_noticia.html}}. \\
    \addlinespace
      \step & World Art Day\footnote{\url{http://www.aimdigital.com.ar/15-de-abril-dia-mundial-del-arte/}}. \\
    \addlinespace
      \step & Max Pradera, an Spanish journalist, posted an unfortunate comment
      about Almudena Cathedral and Notre
      Dame\footnote{\url{https://www.abc.es/internacional/abci-pradera-pudiendose-haber-quemado-almudena-y-quema-notre-dame-201904160310_noticia.html}}. \\
    \addlinespace
      \step & Premiere of the last season of Game of Thrones\footnote{\url{https://www.elmundo.es/television/2019/04/09/5cac665ffc6c8393168b46eb.html}}. \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
  
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So, I've played around a bit and the quick fix seems to be using `parnotes` and a dirty hack to create new lines. It's not the most elegant solution, but it hopefully does what you want it to do.

```
\documentclass{book}                                                                                                 

\usepackage{booktabs}                                                                                                
\usepackage{tabularx}                                                                                                
\usepackage{ragged2e}                                                                                                
\usepackage{makecell}                                                                                                

\usepackage{parnotes} % for footnotes in tables                                                                      

\begin{document}                                                                                                     

\begin{table}[hbtp]                                                                                                  
    \centering                                                                                                       
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ c >{\RaggedRight}X }                                                               
      \toprule                                                                                                       
      \textbf{$e_\#$} & \makecell[cc]{\textbf{Description}} \\                                                       
      \midrule                                                                                                       
      1 & Cathedral of Notre Dame fire during restorations work\parnote{https://www.nytimes.com/es/2019/04/15/notre-\
dame-incendio/\newline % <--- dirty hack for new lines                                                               
      }.  \\ \addlinespace                                                                                           
      2 & Beginning of `Semana Santa' vacances in Madrid\parnote{https://www.abc.es/espana/madrid/abci-semana-santa-\
2019-procesiones-madrid-recorrido-horario-y-programa-201904110105\_noticia.html\newline}. \\ \addlinespace           
      3 & World Art Day\parnote{http://www.aimdigital.com.ar/15-de-abril-dia-mundial-del-arte/\newline}. \\ \addline\
space                                                                                                                
      4 & Max Pradera, an Spanish journalist, posted an unfortunate comment about Almudena Cathedral and Notre Dame\\
parnote{https://www.abc.es/internacional/abci-pradera-pudiendose-haber-quemado-almudena-y-quema-notre-dame-201904160\
310\_noticia.html\newline}. \\ \addlinespace                                                                         
      5 & Premiere of the last season of Game of Thrones\parnote{https://www.elmundo.es/television/2019/04/09/5cac66\
5ffc6c8393168b46eb.html}. \\                                                                                         
      \bottomrule                                                                                                    
    \end{tabularx}                                                                                                   
    \caption{April 15th 2019 most important events}                                                                  
    \label{tab:april-events}                                                                                         
  \end{table}                                                                                                        
  \parnotes % actually create the footnotes, can also be placed inside table, but behaviour different                

\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

It would also be possible to create a `\newcommand` to encompass the `\newline`s, depending on how often you need this.

Comment: Unfortunately your solution (also after removing errors in table's code) doesn't work as OP expected. Footnotes aren't on the bottom of page but below table. However, it works in `tabularx` correctly what `\footnote` doesn't.