# Marginnotes and awesomebox

Tags: footnotes, memoir

I'm using memoir and awesomebox and having trouble with footnotes in the margin.

Initially they were appearing after the box rather than alongside it. so I added

```
\usepackage{footnote}
\makesavenoteenv{tabular}
```

as suggested in [How can I get footnotes in awesomebox?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/504154/how-can-i-get-footnotes-in-awesomebox) but now they appear in (more-or-less) the correct place but are not wrapped:

[image: output]

The code I'm using is:

```
\tipbox{
    \wireshark\  will only export the fields defined to it as 
    columns\footnote{As far as I've been able to ascertain.}: Figure~\vref{fig:wiresharkmain} shows the ones I'm currently using and Figure~\vref{fig:wiresharkpreferences} shows their definitions, should you wish to use them.
    Exporting is started from the menu option
    
    \command{File \rightarrow\ Export Packet Dissections \rightarrow\ As CSV\ldots} 
    
    and may take a few minutes for very large captures. Figure~\vref{fig:csvoutput-wireshark} shows a sample of its structure.
}
```

with a preamble containing:

```
\usepackage{awesomebox}
\let\Huge\LARGE
\setlength{\aweboxrulewidth}{1pt}
\colorlet{abimportant}{IBMBlue80}
\definecolor{abvrulecolor}{RGB}{36,42,36}
\renewcommand{\tipbox}[1]{%
  \awesomebox{\aweboxrulewidth}{\abIconLightBulb}{abimportant}{#1}}
...
\renewcommand*{\sidefootform}{\raggedright}
    \setlength{\footmarkwidth}{-0.2em}
    \setlength{\footmarksep}{-0.2em}
    \setlength{\footparindent}{0em}
\renewcommand{\foottextfont}{\raggedright\footnotesize}
...
\usepackage{footnote}
\makesavenoteenv{tabular}
```

Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass[final,twoside,openright,showtrims,10pt]{memoir} %

\usepackage{awesomebox}

%\usepackage{footnote}
%\makesavenoteenv{tabular}


\begin{document}
    \footnotesinmargin
    
    \chapter{Title}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
    \footnote{Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.}, 
    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
    
    \notebox{
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
        \footnote{Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. }, 
        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
    }
    
\end{document}
```

It has very slightly different symptoms to my full document in that, as-is, the build gives "Float(s) lost. \end{document}" and the footnote is totally lost.  Adding in the commented out lines gives the behavior as described above:

[image]

Comment: Please provide an MWE (from `documentclass...` to `\end{document}` that we can compile that shows your problem I tried to cobble togther an MWE from your code snippets but it did not work. For instance it returned "Undefined color `IBMBlue80`"  Why are you using the `footnote` package when `memoir` supplies footnotes.

Comment: Thanks Peter.  I'll try and build a MWE on Monday: I had hoped someone might know the answer off the top of their head.  As to why I added ```footnote```: because the linked answer suggested it as a fix.  As I wrote, I didn't have that originally, but then the I get the original problem.  I'm not at all surprised it didn't work -- probably even mentioning it here was an error on my part.

Comment: As you already mention, you cannot have footnotes (they are floats) inside a box like this. In this case they are `\marginpar`'s. But the same thing applies, and they cannot escape. One can redefine `\footnotesinmargin` to make it use `\sidepar`, that works, but the placement gets disturbed by `\notebox`. But using the `marginnote` package and its `\marginnote` macro in a redefinition of `\@footnotetext` actually works. But this has the downside that marginnotes (like sidepar) does not move the notes if they get close.