# Why footnote does not work

Tags: pdftex, footnotes

Here is a part of code in which a footnote can not be displayed.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}%
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}%

\begin{document}
    Consequently, the three laws of equality\footnote{It seems that Huntington was
        the first to formalize the three laws of equality.} can also be deduced.
\begin{enumerate}
    \item 
    \begin{tabular}
        [t]{p{1.25in}l}%
        \textbf{Multiplication.} & $a\cdot b\,=\,a-\left(  1-b\right)$ \footnote{We can omit $\cdot$ and $a\cdot b\,=\,ab$.}
    \end{tabular}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

The first footnote works fine. The second footnote is nowhere to be seen despite the referent mark being displayed. I wonder what is the problem.

Comment: Yes, footnotes in a `tabular` environment can be a little tricky. Have you seen this thread? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109467/footnote-in-tabular-environment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For footnote in tables, you can use the pair `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext{…}` outside the table, like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}%
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tablefootnote} 
\usepackage{hyperref}%

\begin{document}

    Consequently, the three laws of equality\footnote{It seems that Huntington was
        the first to formalize the three laws of equality.} can also be deduced.
\begin{enumerate}
    \item
    \begin{tabular}
        [t]{p{1.25in}l}%
        \textbf{Multiplication.} & $a\cdot b\,=\,a-\left( 1-b\right)$ \footnotemark
    \end{tabular}\footnotetext{We can omit $\cdot$ and $a\cdot b\,=\,ab$.}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```